# GraphQLClient could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, graphql

```
var v = new { email = "test1@yahoo.com", password = "fdsafsdfsdf" };
                                var request = new GraphQLRequest
                                {
                                    Query = @"mutation customerCreate($input: CustomerCreateInput!) {
                  customerCreate(input: $input) {
                    userErrors {
                      field
                      message
                    }
                    customer {
                      id
                    }
                  }
                }",
                                    Variables = new
                                    {
                                        input = v
                                    }
        
                                };
        
                                var client = new GraphQLClient("https://kitkatco.myshopify.com/api/graphql");
                                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token", new List<string> { "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" });
                                var response = await client.PostAsync(request);
```

When I run this code, it says, GraphQLClient could not be found. So please have a look and let me know which nuggest package should I install?

Comment: "it says" - who is "it"?  Does this mean that you get an error or runtime exception?  Or is it a compile error?  Which **specific** lines causes it and what is the **exact** message?

Comment: I'm getting this error message on compile time. The error message I am getting is, "The type or namespace GraphQLClient could not be found"

Comment: have you installed the nuget package for GraphQL?  Have you added the necessary `using` statements to your code?  This is a very basic C# error

Comment: Yes, I have installed the GraphQL.Client nugget package.

Comment: Please let me know if there is any other nugget package required.

Comment: I'm getting this error on this line: 

var client = new GraphQLClient("https://kitkatco.myshopify.com/api/graphql");

Comment: Again, Have you added the necessary `using` statements to your code?

Comment: Can you tell me what are those necessary using statements?

Comment: Right click on the errors in the VS editor and it should suggest fixes for you.  Or read the GraphQL documentation to figure out which namespaces the GraphQL client uses.  Or look at sample code to see what using statements are required.

Comment: @PrãshantSaraswat From [graphql-dotnet](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client) on github, I just see `GraphQLHttpClient`, don't find `GraphQLClient`